# PHP foreach loop printing incorrect index

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to generate customized link text for paginated WordPress posts.

Using `<!--nextpage--><!--pagetitle: My Title-->`, I identify a page break and set a title for the next page.

The title is used as the text in the generated link (rather than the WordPress default --plain numbers).

---

Calling `wp_link_pages_titled()` will generate the custom links and print them on the page.

---

The function works as expected, and generates the correct links, but I'm having trouble with the fallback used when `<!--pagetitle: My Title-->` is not present.

When no title is specified, I want to revert back to using 'Page [number]' as the link text. Unfortunately, the fall back is printing the incorrect number.

To test the function, I created a post with 3 paginated sections, and none of these sections have a title.

The links should be printed as

- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3

But are instead printing as

- Page 1
- Page 1
- Page 1

**Note:** The href attribute of the anchor is correct, only the displayed text is wrong.

I've included the foreach loop below. I tried to comment the PHP as much as possible to describe what's happening.

```
// For each paginated section
    foreach ( $pages as $ndx => $part_content) {
        $pageNumber = $ndx + 1;

        // Check to see if the pagetitle quick tag is present
        $has_part_title = strpos( $part_content, '<!--pagetitle:' );

        if( $has_part_title ) {
            $tagEnd = strpos( $part_content, '-->' );
            $title = trim( str_replace( '<!--pagetitle:', '', substr( $part_content, 0, $tagEnd ) ) );
        }
        $output .= ' ';

        // Generate a link to the $pageNumber -- Will not generate link for the current page
        if ( ($pageNumber != $page) || ((!$more) && ($page==1)) ) {
            $output .= _wp_link_page($pageNumber); // Page number is correct here - the link generated is accurate
        }

        echo 'Page Number: '.$pageNumber.' -- Link Generated <br /> '; // This is a test to check the value of $pageNumber. Value prints as expected

        // If the pagetitle is present, use it. If not, pring 'Page [$pageNumber]'
        $title = isset( $title ) && ( strlen( $title ) > 0 ) ? $title : 'Page '.$pageNumber;
        $output .= $link_before . $title . $link_after;

        echo 'Page Number Again: '.$pageNumber.' -- Title Generated <br> '; // This is a test to check the value of $pageNumber. Value prints as expected

        // Close the generated link -- will not execute when $pageNumber == the current page
        if ( ($pageNumber != $page) || ((!$more) && ($page==1)) ) {
            $output .= '</a>';
        }
    }

    // Close the "list"
    $output .= $after;
}

/*  Worth noting: Links are added to a single output string and printed in one go after the foreach executes.
    Seems like it would be better to print each link individually */
if ( $echo )
    echo $output; // When $output prints, the link text for every page is 'Page 1' for some reason, the page number here is not displayed correctly
return $output;
```

Why does the `echo $pageNumber;` print the correct value, but the `'Page '.$pageNumber` print only 'Page 1' for every link?

I'm sure I've missed something obvious, but I can't place what it is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have `if ($echo)` towards the end of the script?

Comment: Print out `$ndx` I bet it's 0 every time. Instead just keep track of `$pageNumber` and increment it each iteration

Comment: @Floris This is a function I pulled from somewhere else. I believe the $echo is tied to the WordPress wp_link_pages() function this is meant to augment. A boolean switch to either print the links or return a variable.

Comment: @ElefantPhace it's definitely not 0 every time. The generated href attributes are correct, and those rely on the same variable. Also, as noted in the commented code, I printed the variable as a test before and after the line in question and confirmed that the value was correct. The problem was tied to the isset() call. --See Mark Dunphy's awnser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is off.  Think carefully about the line that sets `$title`.

```
$title = isset( $title ) && ( strlen( $title ) > 0 ) ? $title : 'Page '.$pageNumber;
```

When `$title` isn't set (the first iteration, where `$pageNumber` is 1), you set `$title` to "Page 1". From that point on, `$title` is set and will not change.  What you're basically saying is "If I have already set `$title` to a value, set it equal to itself".

Comment: That's it exactly, thank you. It seems embarrassingly obvious now that you've pointed it out (which is what I expected would happen)